# How to get output in list in neo4j based on subgroup?

Tags: neo4j

I'm very new for neo4j. how we can group and get output in array of array.

[image]
I need output like
[[ST001,ST0011,ST00111],[ST002,ST0022,ST00222],.....,[ST006,ST0066,ST00666]]

Advance thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use apoc.coll.sort:

```
MATCH (n:Node)
WITH n
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)--(m:Node)
WITH COLLECT(m.key) as arr, n.key AS key
WITH arr + key AS arr
WITH apoc.coll.sort(arr) AS arr
RETURN DISTINCT arr
```

Which for:

```
MERGE (a1:Node {key:'A'}) 
MERGE (a2:Node {key:'B'}) 
MERGE (a3:Node {key:'C'}) 
MERGE (b1:Node {key:'D'}) 
MERGE (b2:Node {key:'E'}) 
MERGE (b3:Node {key:'F'}) 
MERGE (c1:Node {key:'G'})

MERGE (a1)-[:DISTANCE]->(a2)
MERGE (a2)-[:DISTANCE]->(a3)
MERGE (a3)-[:DISTANCE]->(a1)
MERGE (b1)-[:DISTANCE]->(b2)
MERGE (b2)-[:DISTANCE]->(b3)
MERGE (b3)-[:DISTANCE]->(b1)
```

returns:

```
╒═══════════════╕
│arr            │
╞═══════════════╡
│["A", "B", "C"]│
├───────────────┤
│["D", "E", "F"]│
├───────────────┤
│["G"]          │
└───────────────┘
```

You can also add one more `COLLECT` if needed:

```
MATCH (n:Node)
WITH n
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)--(m:Node)
WITH COLLECT(m.key) as arr, n.key AS key
WITH arr + key as arr
WITH apoc.coll.sort(arr) AS arr
WITH DISTINCT arr AS arr
RETURN COLLECT(arr) AS arr
```

to get:

```
╒═════════════════════════════════════════╕
│arr                                      │
╞═════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[["A", "B", "C"], ["D", "E", "F"], ["G"]]│
└─────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: thankyou @nimrod serok this solution is working.
Instant of keys, I used name property
I got desired out.

output:
[["ST001", "ST0011", "ST00111"], ["ST002", "ST0022", "ST00222"], ["ST003", "ST0033", "ST00333"], ["ST004", "ST0044", "ST00444"], ["ST005", "ST0055", "ST00555"], ["ST006", "ST0066", "ST00666"]]